# no suitable user-defined conversion from utility::string_t to std::string

Tags: c++, string, casablanca

I am using the casablanca C++ Rest library to make HTTP requests.

The problem is that this gives a utility::string_t string as output and I can't quite find any way to convert this to a classic std::string. Any ideas?

```
client.request(methods::GET).then([](http_response response)
{
  if(response.status_code() == status_codes::OK)
  {
    string_t s = response.extract_string().get();
  }
});
```

Comment: Isn't utility::string_t a typedef for std::string?
Where's the problem?

Comment: So last REST SDK have some type problmes, if you work with. latest versions have: typedef std::wstring string_t;

Comment: For reference, http://casablanca.codeplex.com/discussions/572948

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the documentation for C++ REST SDK from github, you'll find a `typedef`

[C++ Rest SDK - utility Namespace Reference](http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaceutility.html)

```
typedef std::string     string_t;
```

So no need to convert it. Both are same types.

Comment: This only applies on non-Windows. On Windows, this typedef looks like `typedef std::wstring string_t;`

Comment: utility does support the function like `utility::conversions::to_utf8string`

Answer (score 11):

Depending on what platform you are compiling for, the `utility::string_t` type will be typedef'd to either `std::wstring` (on Windows) or `std::string` (on Linux/OSX).

To get a classic utf-8 `std::string` regardless of platform, take a look at `utility::conversions::to_utf8string`.

[reference documentation](http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/namespaceutility_1_1conversions.html#ac8d51543ee17a75bc289040c802d51af)

Comment: This is the only thing tat worked for me on Windows, with C++ REST SDK 2.7.0. The utility::string_t from using value.as_string() was not accepted as std::string.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows Phone 8.1 there is this define:

```
typedef std::wstring     string_t;
```

I used this:

```
string_t toStringT = U("sample");
std::string fromStringT(toStringT.begin(), toStringT.end());
```

or:

```
std::string fromStringT(conversions::to_utf8string(toStringT));
```